# Can I create an OS image of more than 10GB on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to boot about 500 instances with an specific image to do a job with big files that requires POSIX access to more than 10GB. According to that doc https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images it's impossible create a boot disk of more than 10GB and I need POSIX access to more than 10 GB. Does this mean I will need to create another non-boot disk on each instance with disk space I need? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a bigger boot disk on Google Compute Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021214/how-to-get-a-bigger-boot-disk-on-google-compute-engine)

Answer (score 1):

That doc refers to a limit to the size of the operating system Image, not the size of the boot disk.

You can create a boot disk of any size, and then use it when creating the instance, e.g:

gcutil adddisk "disk-1" --size_gb="15" --zone="europe-west1-b" --source_image="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20140522"

gcutil addinstance "instance-1" --zone="europe-west1-b" --machine_type="n1-standard-1" --network="default" --external_ip_address="ephemeral" --metadata="sshKeys:" --disk="disk-1,deviceName=disk-1,mode=READ_WRITE,boot" --auto_delete_boot_disk="true"

See: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#create_disk

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) to create images on GCE which will auto-resize on boot. I have created a [repo](https://github.com/mbrukman/stackexchange-answers/tree/master/stackoverflow/24023916) specifically for this question which has a demo of an auto-resizing image using recent versions of either Debian-7 backports or container-optimized VM images.

It uses [`cloud-initramfs-growroot`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/cloud-initramfs-growroot):

> **automatically resize the root partition on first boot**
>
> This package adds functionality to an initramfs built by initramfs-tools. When installed, the initramfs will repartition a disk to make the root volume consume all space that follows it.
>
> You most likely do not want this package unless you know what you are doing. It is primarily interesting in a virtualized environment when a disk can provisioned with a size larger than its original size. In this case, with this package installed, you can automatically use the new space without requiring a reboot to re-read the partition table.

See my script [`growroot.sh`](https://github.com/mbrukman/stackexchange-answers/blob/master/stackoverflow/24023916/auto-resize/growroot.sh) for details and how you can adapt it to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create a boot disk larger than 10GB but then you'll need to repartition it, because by default, the provided VM images expand to 10GB so you'll need to use [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd) and run `fdisk`, reboot, and then run `resize2fs` to expand the usable space to the full size of the disk. You can automate it so that it runs as part of instance creation by using [startup scripts](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript).
2. Another alternative is to create a separate persistent disk and attach it separately, but then it won't be a boot disk but just a data disk. For that you can use the instructions on the [same page](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#create_disk), namely:

   - `gcutil adddisk [...]`
   - `gcutil attachdisk [...]`, unless the boot and data disks are added during instance creation via `gcutil addinstance --disk=disk1 --disk=disk2 [...]`, in which case this is not needed
   - `/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount [...]` to automate the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without having to manually resize/partition/format a disk or any of the complications introduced in all the other answers on StackOverflow. Please see my answer here for how this can be done: [How to get a bigger boot disk on Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021214/how-to-get-a-bigger-boot-disk-on-google-compute-engine/28136950#28136950)