# How to increase the size of my instance disk on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to increase the size of my disk of an instance in *Google Compute Engine* without losing my current files, how to do in Google Cloud?. I have currently just 10GB and will soon be 100%.

I appreciate any tip. This is the screenshot when I start the terminal:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can size of the root disk in Google compute engine be increased?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381686/how-can-size-of-the-root-disk-in-google-compute-engine-be-increased)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot?hl=en) of your current disk. Once done, create a new disk from this snapshot specifying the required size.

If your end goal is to have an instance with the higher size of boot disk than, you can directly create a new instance from this snapshot with the required disk size from [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com), instead of creating the disk and than creating a new instance from this disk.

I hope that helps.